# A recursive query to get data by per month basis

Tags: mysql

how would you write a recursive query that can bring back data grouped by months?

As an example, something like this...

```html
Month Amount
Jan   £1000
Feb   £1500
March £2000
```

Currently I'm running 3 separate queries that calculates the sum of all transactions within a month and then groups them and then I union everything. This however doesn't factor in coming months or previous months. It's hardcoded per se.

What I'm doing is the following for every month.

```html
WHERE processing_time >= 2019-02-01 00:00:00
AND processing_time <= 2019-02-28 23:59:59
```

I need something that can show me 12 months worth of data but that also changes dynamically.

So March 2018 to Feb 2018 if I checked today and April 2018 to March 2019 if I check next month.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Comment: That's not a recursive query. Just use `GROUP BY` the month. Provide some example data if you need a specific solution.

Comment: @TheImpaler i think he needs a "calendar" table for missing months. but hard to say for sure without example data and or expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to solve it with recursive queries. you can use a "calendar" table to fill in the missing values.  
A MySQL/MariaDB number generator comes to mind for month name generations.

```
SELECT 
 MONTHNAME(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH)
FROM (

SELECT 
 @row := @row + 1 AS number
FROM (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row2
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT @row := -1 
) init_user_params 
) AS number_generator
WHERE
 number_generator.number BETWEEN 0 AND 12
ORDER BY 
 number_generator.number ASC
```

**Result**

```
| MONTHNAME(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------- |
| March                                                            |
| April                                                            |
| May                                                              |
| June                                                             |
| July                                                             |
| August                                                           |
| September                                                        |
| October                                                          |
| November                                                         |
| December                                                         |
| January                                                          |
| February                                                         |
| March                                                            |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRjpwVQBYXBHDrwMZkzwyB/4)

**Edit**

> This is very close but can I also get the start and end days of each
>   month?

The last day is not that hard because there is a function for it in MySQL. 
For the first day you need to be more creative with `LAST_DAY()` in combination with intervals like `+1 DAY` and `-1 MONTH` to get the first day of the month.

```
SELECT 
   MONTHNAME(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH)
 , ((LAST_DAY(CAST(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH AS DATE)))
        + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS first_day_of_month
 , (LAST_DAY(CAST(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH AS DATE))) AS last_day_of_month
```

**Results**

```
| MONTHNAME(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) | first_day_of_month | last_day_of_month |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------- | ------------------ | ----------------- |
| March                                                            | 2019-03-01         | 2019-03-31        |
| April                                                            | 2019-04-01         | 2019-04-30        |
| May                                                              | 2019-05-01         | 2019-05-31        |
| June                                                             | 2019-06-01         | 2019-06-30        |
| July                                                             | 2019-07-01         | 2019-07-31        |
| August                                                           | 2019-08-01         | 2019-08-31        |
| September                                                        | 2019-09-01         | 2019-09-30        |
| October                                                          | 2019-10-01         | 2019-10-31        |
| November                                                         | 2019-11-01         | 2019-11-30        |
| December                                                         | 2019-12-01         | 2019-12-31        |
| January                                                          | 2020-01-01         | 2020-01-31        |
| February                                                         | 2020-02-01         | 2020-02-29        |
| March                                                            | 2020-03-01         | 2020-03-31        |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRjpwVQBYXBHDrwMZkzwyB/4)

Comment: This is very close but can I also get the start and end days of each month?

Comment: See mine comment under your question @Dally iám not going to geuss more which data you also need.

Comment: @Dally posted a edit about the first and last day it should also work with leap years, if you need more i suggest you making a MCVE like i suggested

Comment: I'm getting an error when running your query mate. "Unknown table 'number_generator' in field list". Am I missing something?

Comment: I wish MySQL had `generate_series()` like PostgreSQL. That would make your query so much shorter. Anyway +1.

Comment: @Dally where was still a mysql_number_generator alias in the anwers SQL the demo’s all worked, its changed now

Comment: indeed @TheImpaler but the SQL standard i believe does not have a standard for generating numbers ranges... A [basic SQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRjpwVQBYXBHDrwMZkzwyB/7) which works on most databases systems or with [window functions](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRjpwVQBYXBHDrwMZkzwyB/9) which is more optimized and so much shorter